# ERD for tables from different database schemas

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have got various database schemas on a server in oracle sql and when I run the database sql modeler to get the ERD diagram it's showing me the table connections within the different database schemas only and not across tables in different schemas. However, I was asked to pull out data from tables which have common keys for joining from the various databases schemas. However, the ERD diagram is not showing these connections. Is there any way one can identify which tables from the various schemas have common primary/foreign keys and can be connected?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what ERD modeler you are using and whether you made the constraints across databases explicit or not.

If you're not seeing them, you need to figure out which of these is true: is it the ERD modeler that can't show the constraints, or are the constraints actually missing.

If your modeler can show inter-database constraints, then add them in and you'll see them.

(If you want a more specific answer, show part of the schema with a table that has a inter-schema constraint.)